# Python - Beautiful Soup - Getting a link find_all

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap a website using beautifulsoup, my problem is that I am only trying to get a link in the Html source but end up with a terrible list of every

```
<div class="table-list-cell py-3 pl-3 v-align-middle member-avatar-cell css-truncate pr-0">
  <a href="/Member1">
  <img alt="@Member1" class="avatar float-left" height="48" src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/xxxxxxx" width="48" />
</a>
```

I only want to get the /Member1 or @Member1 my code look like this :

```
Membres={}
response = requests.get('https://github.com/orgs/xxxxxxxx/people?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
for e in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"table-list-cell py-3 pl-3 v-align-middle member-avatar-cell css-truncate pr-0"}):
    for d in e.find_all("a"):
        for f in d.find_all("img alt="):
            Membres[f]={}
```

So I have try to cut the line 'for f in ....' and creat a direct link such as :

```
for d in e.find_all("a", href=True):
```

Still way to many informations in my keys, if someone got a way to just get the Member1 name.

Thank you

Comment: You want a list like `['/Member1','/Member2','/Member3', ....]`?

Comment: Exactly ['/Member1'] or ['@Member1'] in order to scrap their followers and friend after to create a network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
s = """
<div class="table-list-cell py-3 pl-3 v-align-middle member-avatar-cell css-truncate pr-0">
    <a href="/Member1">
    <img alt="@Member1" class="avatar float-left" height="48" src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/xxxxxxx" width="48" />
  </a>
 """
user_data = dict(re.findall('<img alt="@(.*?)" class="avatar float-left" height="48" src="(.*?)" width="48" />', s))
```

Output:

```
{'Member1': 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/xxxxxxx'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a simple list comprehension to extract the `href` out of the `<a>` tags:

```
for e in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"table-list-cell py-3 pl-3 v-align-middle member-avatar-cell css-truncate pr-0"}):
    my_list = [a['href'] for a in e.find_all('a')]
```

which gives:

```
>>> my_list
['/Member1']
```

---

To put them in a dictionary you can use a similar syntax:

```
for e in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"table-list-cell py-3 pl-3 v-align-middle member-avatar-cell css-truncate pr-0"}):
    my_dict = {a['href']:'' for a in e.find_all('a')}
```

which gives:

```
>>> my_dict
{'/Member1': ''}
```

Comment: My bad, I am not trying to get the list of Member, but tu put Member in dictionary such as : Member_Dict.keys()   ['/Member1', 'Member2'...]

Comment: what would be the value of each key? Or it's just not an issue for now?

Comment: It's not a issue for now, I am going to give them a value later but first I try to put all the Member as primary keys in the dictionary

Comment: @LucasD I see, I've just edited the answer to fit your problem.

Comment: @LucasD I'm glad to help! If the answer works for you, you should [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Sorry Vinicius, when I try your code it give me a dictionary but only with the last User of the page, all other users are not in the keys (I tried to make a loop : while i<(number of users I want to scrap) [... Your Code ...] i=i+1. But this only scrap the first User